# is there any way to bin an 3d surface created in CUDA to an OpenGL texture?

Tags: opengl, cuda, glsl, textures

here is  the  scenario:
I pass an 3D  OpenGL Texture to CUDA by cudaBindTextureToArray transforming it with a non rigid transformation and  writed it to a  3d surface  and  then I want  to pass it by a texture to GLSL shader for volume rendering. and GLSL only knows texture id?how I use this 3d surface as an ordinary OpenGL texture?

**pseudo code**

craete a texture with opengl like this

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0,............);
```

pass it to cuda

create and fill a surface with

```
cutilSafeCall(cudaBindSurfaceToArray(volumeTexOut, outTexture->content));
......
..
  cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc3DArray(&vol->content, &vol->channelDesc, dataSize,  cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore ) );
```

after transformation,..

```
  surf3Dwrite(short(voxel), volumeTexOut, sizeof(short)*x1,y1, z1);
```

and now i want to use this surface as an opengl Texture  and pass it to GLSL

Comment: I do not want to create a new memory because the memory is there on card

Comment: Before you call `glTexImage3D`, you have to call `glCreateTextures`, right? So then you can pass the texture just like you would any other one. (`glBindTexture`...) GLSL can use 3D samplers just like 2D and 1D ones. Or is the question about *How to bind textures to shaders?*

Comment: if you mean by glCreateTextures ,glGenTextures yes. but when i use glTexImage3D  it needs  a pointer on host  and then generate texture from it on device .but  I already have the buffer on device and only I want to dedicate and  id to a new texture with this existing buffer on  device created with cuda surface.

Comment: Why do you want to create a new texture? What is the problem with passing the existing id (which has been filled by CUDA)? (and yes, I was mistaken, I meant `glGenTextures`)

Comment: no, when we crate a surface in cuda it hasnot any id  an isnot related to any  texture   cudaBindSurfaceToArray(volumeTexOut,outTexture->content); i  use and opengl existing texture  ,crate a new surface with the same dimension transform existing texture and put result in the surface and now I want to dedicate a texture id to this  surface,it must be possible they have the same structure

Comment: *i use and opengl existing texture* - do you have its id? Does it contents reflect what you want to render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: The APIs suggested below are quite old and have been deprecated. Please see the current [Graphics Interop APIs for CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP)

CUDA OpenGL interop is (unfortunately) a one-way API: to interoperate between CUDA and OpenGL you must allocate all memory needed in your GL code using OpenGL, and then bind it to CUDA arrays or device pointers in order to access it in CUDA. You cannot do the opposite (allocate memory with CUDA and access it from OpenGL). This goes for data that is either read or written by CUDA.

So for your output, you want to allocate the 3D texture in OpenGL, *not* with `cudaMalloc3DArray()`.  Then you want to call `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` with the `cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore`, and then bind a surface to the resulting array  using `cudaBindSurfaceToArray`. This is discussed in section 3.2.11.1 of the CUDA 4.2 CUDA C Programming Guide. The CUDA reference guide provides full documentation on the functions I mentioned.

Note that surface writes require a compute capability 2.0 or higher GPU.

Comment: cudaBindSurfaceToArray is listed as deprecated, although it doesn’t list a replacement for it in the documentation. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__SURFACE.html

Comment: @Bram correct. Added a link to current graphics interop APIs.